# Did Draupadi want Karna as her sixth husband?

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas, karna, draupadi

I heard this version in an old telugu film which praises Karna. I thought that was just a created [story](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZ5vN.png) for the sake of film. I didn't believe that version. But these days, a dialogue is made popular who are relating draupadi to raped victims whose translation is like this

`We accept Draupadi who has five husbands as a virtuous wife. Why not accept raped victims?`.  and many similar dialogues
This version is supported by a story which is a part of a book named [Jaya: An illustrated retelling of Mahabharata](http://devdutt.com/books/jaya-3.html)  written by a famous writer [Devdutt Pattanaik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devdutt_Pattanaik). That story is below.

[image]

**My question**:

- Did Draupadi want karna as her sixth husband?
- Was Draupadi unhappy about her husbands anytime?

Please quote sanskrit verses too if possible.

Comment: @sv. My bad. I was thinking something while typing this. Is it want or wanted? I think it was wanted since it is past tense.

Comment: NP. I'm not an expert in English but see [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100724225816AAdfe1U) & [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/106248).

Comment: That story mentioned by Pattanaik is from some folktale in western India so no Sanskrit scriptural basis.